# phpredis on windows 7 64bit xampp

Tags: php, windows, redis, 64-bit

I'm trying to make Redis work on my windows machine for development purposes. I already made Redis up and running on my Ubuntu 10.04 server with phpredis client.

At the moment on my windows machine i can start Redis server, because it requires no installation and it is good enaugh for development, but I can't figure out how to install phpredis. It seems very confusing, I already spend two days working on this and no result.

I have cloned source files with Git, but i did that using Git Bash, but that was last command who worked in the same way as ubuntu. I also have downloaded two .dll files, one with 'ts' and another with 'nts', have no idea what is the difference :/

http://commandperls.com/install-phpredis/
there is manual how to install phpredis, but it works only on ubuntu for my. I'm very newbie for a command line and I'm not sure if this even suppose to work on windows, like with cmd or git bash.

So my question is, how can I make that phpredis work on windows? Is there is any way to make that happen? I know there is Predis and I already tried that one, but because I'm planning to use phpredis on my server, i would like to use same on development machine.

Comment: Indeed, the installation and making redis work on windows was very daunting for me as well. After using it successfully I pieced together an article on Linkedin, here there you go:
[using php on windows with php](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-redis-windows-php-shekhar-joshi)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found it! Apologizing for misapprehension, but all this situation is really confusing for guy who such a little about servers management. Anyway, below is my solution.

http://code.google.com/p/pecl-win/downloads/detail?name=php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll&can=2&q=

Link above provides .dll file, which in my case must be copied to: `C:\xampp\php\ext` and add a line in to php.ini file `extension=php_redis.dll` and lastly restart apache2 service.

And that's it, nothing has to be installed, as long as redis server already up and running this will provide connection between php and redis!

**2020-05-06 update**

Seems like previous url only contains outdated .dll files.
@Niz provided in the comments an updated url where you can download the correct version of redis DLL for your windows. Make sure to download the one that matches your redis and php versions.

https://pecl.php.net/package/redis

Comment: Does this still work for you? I've tried following your steps in my WAMP installation but I get the message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_redis-2.1.3-5.3-ts.dll - %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no clue, haven't used it for a long time now. All I can say that I was using it on pretty much standard XAMPP installation on 64bit windows machine.

Comment: i tried adding it, but for some reason i can access my redis service

Comment: @Thomas, you need to download x86 version of php_redis.dll and put it in your C:\xampp\php\ext

Comment: the latest binaries can be found in the official repo in https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/X.y.z/windows
where X.y.z is the redis version. As of 13.02.2020, the latest version available in the pecl repo is 5.1.1, so the url to download would be https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.1.1/windows

Comment: How do you know if you downloaded the right redis.dll file ?  Should I base it on my redis-server version??? I'm using laragon

Comment: you should download the one that matches your php version and redis version

Comment: "Nothing has to be installed" is completely false, this still requires integrating with the Redis server which requires a separate install/setup process.

Answer (score 10):

You can still find up to date compiled dll binaries of Redis(and many more) at the following location:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/redis/2.2.7/

```
    # php -i | find "Architecture"
    # php -i | find "Thread"
```

Answer (score 1):

Php 7 with redis support for xammp there are new binaries available in:
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/redis/

Comment: I don't understand the downvote: it is a valid link for recent versions of Php.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

**Answer Referred from this Article** : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-redis-windows-php-shekhar-joshi/

**Check all the information from phpinfo() such as x86 , php version and Thread Safety.**

**Useful Portion from the Article :**

Download PECL extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows , you need to know which version would work for you. First of all check out your php version and know whether thread safety is enabled or not(you can do this by using phpinfo()). Download the appropriate version of the dll, for thread safety enabled use ts version otherwise use nts version. Extract the contents and copy the .dll file in xamp/php/ext. Next, open the php.ini file located at(xampp/php) and add this string extension="php_redis.dll" together with other extensions.

Comment: Hey how do I know the `redis.dll` should I download? should I base it on what redis-server