# Issue Regarding Redis in broadcasting with Redis in Laravel 7.5 and OS is Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, redis, windows-10

I am using **Laravel Version:** 7.5 , **PHP VERSION:** 7.4.8, **SERVER:** APACHE (XAMPP), **PACKAGE:** Redis, OS: Windows 10.

I have install Redis in my system and I am able to run redis-server successfully but when I use this in Laravel for broadcasting it will throw error which is as follows "Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled".
[Please find attached screenshot about error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KnQ6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpredis on windows 7 64bit xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178600/phpredis-on-windows-7-64bit-xampp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer add the key in `.env` file which is as follows:
`REDIS_CLIENT=predis`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed redis?
https://redis.io/download

what are your environment variable settings? For Redis:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=secret
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and are you using laravel echo server? what are your laravel-echo-server setting?

```
{
"authHost": "http://localhost",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "id",
        "key": "key"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
        "password" : "secret"
    },
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"secureOptions": 67108864,
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:80",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
}
```

have you started your echo-server and queue? Use the following

```
php artisan queue:work
laravel-echo-server start
```

also install predis/predis

Comment: Hello Bomzan, Thanks for quick reply. Yes I had installed redis. And I setup all the environment variable as you suggested. `php artisan queue:work` command is successfully run but when I run the command `php artisan queue:work`  it through warning `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_redis.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_redis.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_redis.dll.
dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`